# Übersetzung von "(post)graduate student"

Tags: single-word-request

Aus [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_school) (Hervorhebungen sind meine):

> Many universities award graduate degrees; a graduate school is not necessarily a separate institution. While the term "graduate school" is typical in the United States and often used elsewhere (e.g. Canada), "postgraduate education" is also used in some English-speaking countries (Australia, Canada, Ireland, India, Bangladesh, New Zealand, Pakistan and the UK) to refer to the spectrum of education beyond a bachelor's degree. Those attending graduate schools are called **"graduate students"** (in both American and British English), or often in British English as "postgraduate students" and, colloquially, **"postgraduates"** and "postgrads". Degrees awarded to graduate students include master's degrees, doctoral degrees, and other postgraduate qualifications such as graduate certificates and professional degrees.

Gibt es ein deutsches Wort für "graduate student"? [Dieses Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/graduate%20student) schlägt das Wort "Jungakademiker" vor. Ich glaube aber, dass das nicht zutrifft, denn ein "graduate student" ist noch nicht wirklich ein "Akademiker".

Comment: Ich arbeite selbst im akademischen Umfeld, habe aber das Wort `Jungakademiker` noch nie gehört. Ansonsten kann ich mich nur der Antwort von @ThS anschließen: ein `(post)grad student` kann sowohl ein Masterstudent als auch ein Doktorand sein. Einen Überbegriff gibt es dafür im Deutschen nicht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt keine direkte 1:1-Übersetzung für "(post)graduate student".

Ein (amerikanischer) "grad student" macht zunächst einen Master und arbeitet danach auf einen Doktorabschluss hin. Das heißt, in Deutschland ist es am ehesten mit *Masterstudent* oder mit *Doktorand* zu übersetzen, abhängig davon, in welcher Phase er ist.

Comment: Der Versuch, im Rahmen der Bologna-Reform den amerikanischen 'Bachelor' als Normalabschluß durchzusetzen, so daß die Mehrzahl der Studenten nicht auch noch den 'Master' anstrebt, muß als gescheitert betrachtet werden. Die 'Graduation' fällt also normalerweise mit dem Master zusammen, d.h. 'Doktorand' ist m.E. nach wie vor die am häufigsten richtige Übersetzung.